# Какова этимология слов "монгол" и "татар"?

Tags: этимология, история

Есть мнение, что *мо**Н**гол* производное от *могол*.
А *татар* — от *та**Р**тар*. Верно ли это?

Comment: Есть такое слово «татар»?

Comment: Имел ввиду татары, конечно же.

Comment: @shampar я - татар, ты - татар, они - татары. я - армян, ты - армян, мы - армяны

Answer (score 1):

"Могол" и "монгол" - это разновидности одного и того же слова в разных языках. А по поводу этнонима "татары" (Вы, видимо, его имеете в виду), существует множество версий происхождения слова, но все они исходят из тюркского, персидского и китайского языков, а никак не греческого Тартара, который никак не мог быть известен кочевникам на севере Китая.

Правда, стоит отметить, что в западноевропейской средневековой традиции подобное смешение всё-таки было и татар воспринимали исчадиями ада, но это было ещё до зарождения научного знания.

Answer (score 0):

Если брать историю, то в русском языке закрепилось "могол" применительно к государству на севере Индии XVI-XIX веков, а "монголы" — за собственно монголами начиная с века XIII. Что тут от чего произошло, совершенно не очевидно. Вернее всего, просто вариант "могол" пришел из Европы. Кстати, в отношении самих моголов нет единого мнения об их происхождении, потомками "монголов" (темуридов) наверняка была только верхушка, правители.

С татарами и тартарами история аналогичная. На многих европейских языках "тартарами" называют именно татар. Является ли это чисто фонетическим вариантом или появилось в результате смешения с греческим Тартаром — сказать наверняка нельзя. Кроме того, Тартарией (Татарией) в европейской географической традиции называлась огромная область от Каспия до Тихого океана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трудно сказать, является ли это название чисто фонетическим вариантом.

Тем не менее, в обоих случаях первичными для **русского языка** следует считать варианты монгол и татар(ы).